# Having troubles to get return from a function within an object

Tags: javascript, function, this

I'm trying to understand the use of "this".  I can't get the age from the function calculation(undefined). What am I doing wrong?

```js
const reina= {
    firstName: 'Reina',
    birthYear: 1998,
    location:'Tokyo',
    friends:['Chihomi','Lei','Louis'],
    calcAge: function(){
     this.age= 2021 - this.birthYear;
    return this.age;
    }

}
console.log(reina.age);
```

output:

```
undefined
```

Comment: The function hasn’t been run so age would be undefined. Also I’m not sure `this` will be what you think it will be.

Answer (score 2):

You never called the `calcAge` function.

```js
const reina = {
  firstName: 'Reina',
  birthYear: 1998,
  location: 'Tokyo',
  friends: ['Chihomi', 'Lei', 'Louis'],
  calcAge: function() {
    this.age = 2021 - this.birthYear;
    return this.age;
  }

}
console.log(reina.calcAge());
console.log(reina.age);
```

It seems like a getter is most appropriate in this case.

```js
const reina = {
  firstName: 'Reina',
  birthYear: 1998,
  location: 'Tokyo',
  friends: ['Chihomi', 'Lei', 'Louis'],
  get age() {
    return 2021 - this.birthYear;
  }
}
console.log(reina.age);
```

Comment: I see. So, if i want to be able to get age only using(reina.age) then I will have to define it outside the function right?

Comment: @ReinaSUZUKI you can implement something called a “getter”. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of reusability, I would use a Class instead of assigning to an object. That would leave less code in the long run.

`this` points to the current scope you're in, whether your in a method, an object or a class.

To create a class, you need to add a constructor, that you can send in parameters to. As you can see in the code, `this` in the constructor means the `class Person` when I call `calcAge()`.

I also added `new Date().getFullYear()` which should be self-explanatory.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(firstName, birthYear, location, friends) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
    this.location = location;
    this.friends = friends;
    this.age = this.calcAge(birthYear);
  }
  
  calcAge(birthYear) {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - birthYear;
  }
}

const reina   = new Person('Reina', 1998, 'Tokyo', ['Chihomi', 'Lei', 'Louis']);
const rickard = new Person('Rickard', 1890, 'Stockholm', ['Beatrice', 'Gretchen', 'Hans']);

console.log(reina.firstName, reina.age);
console.log(rickard.firstName, rickard.age);
```